# Share code between very similar Git repositories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, version-control

I have developed a Rails application as a "template" that also works on its own. Now I forked this in git to build a second app with very similar code but some important changes.
Newer features, however, are developed in the template Rails app and I would like to be able to use them in the forked app without the code in the forked app being able to override code in the template app.
I realize now, that forking wasn't an ideal strategy because it is basically the opposite of what I want. What alternative do I have? I looked at git submodules, but because the two apps have largely the same code this does not seem ideal.

Comment: Consider using a package manager or some other tool which allows for code sharing between apps? Git isn't a great tool for this (in my opinion)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? My problem is mostly, that I don't have distinct block of  code to share but one template app and very similar "child apps" that only differ in a few (but important) lines of code.

Comment: What you're looking for is *abstraction* or *levels of indirection* or similar. This has little to do with repositories and a lot to do with computer programming.